# What does the following neo4j error mean?

Tags: graph, neo4j, nosql

I'm trying to run some queries on neo4j but I'm getting the following error:

```
Something went wrong: "Error: Reference.set failed: 
  First argument contains a string greater than 10485760 utf8 bytes in property  
  'users.auth0|5aeb486d249b5d6bdbe1a2d5.grass.0.data' 
     ('{"0":"{","1":"\"","2":"0","3":"\"","4":":","5":"\"...')" 
and the application can't recover.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show the full stacktrace in your question?